# Matlab: fmincon converging to infeasible point, not meeting equality constraint

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to use fmincon to optimize x such that R*x is minimized while x can be values between 0 and 1.5 and the `sum(x) = 3`

```
R = transpose([6 6 6 6 6 6 6 9 9 9 9 13 13 13 13 9 9 9 9 6 6 6 6 6]);
x0 = zeros(24,1);
  f='0';
       for j=1:24
           s='%d*x(%d)';
           s=sprintf(s,R(j),j);
           g='%s+%s';
           f=sprintf(g,f,s);
       end

A = ones(2,24);
A(2,:) = -1;
b = [1.5; 0];    % Want x's to be between 0 and 1.5

Aeq = ones(1,24);
beq = [3];

%Bounds
lb = zeros(24,1);
ub = ones(24,1);

x = fmincon(f, x0, A, b,Aeq, beq,lb,ub);
```

I want the sum of x to equal 3 (attempted to show this with equivalency matrices Aeq and beq). The following error was shown when I run the code:

> converged to an infeasible point

It should be noted that this code shows that `sum(x) = 2.25` instead of `sum(x) = 3`

Answer (score 1):

First, your function definition can be shortened to:

```
R = [6 6 6 6 6 6 6 9 9 9 9 13 13 13 13 9 9 9 9 6 6 6 6 6];
f = @(x)R*x;
```

Second, your initial point `x0` does not satisfy your constraints, so let's change it to:

```
x0 = zeros(24,1)+3/24;
```

so that the sum of `x` is equal to 3.

Next, since you have a constant upper and lower bounds on x, you don't need to use `A` and `b` matrices, so we get rid of them and replace them with empty matrices `[]`. We will rely only on `lb` and `ub` instead:

```
lb = zeros(24,1);
ub = 1.5*ones(24,1);
```

Finally, we start `fmincon` by using

```
x = fmincon(f, x0,[],[],Aeq, beq,lb,ub)

Optimization completed because the objective function is non-decreasing in 
feasible directions, to within the default value of the optimality tolerance,
and constraints are satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>


x =

    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
```